# Mysql replication with different column definitions on Master and Slave

Tags: mysql, replication, multi-source-replication

Suppose that I have below table definitions in Master and Slave :

```
master> CREATE TABLE t1 (id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 c1 INT(11) NOT NULL,
 c2 INT(11),
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`c1`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

slave>  CREATE TABLE t1 (id INT(11) NOT NULL,
 c1 INT(11) NOT NULL,
 c2 INT(11),
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`c1`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

As you can see `t1` table in slave does not have the *AUTO_INCREMENT* to the column `id`. Would it raise any errors because the different definitions of column `id` ?

Comment: If its row based - probably not. I haven't tried though.

Comment: This should be fine, as long as the `binlog_format` on the master *is* set to `ROW`. Otherwise, it will definitely fail or eventually become inconsistent.  The question is... why does the column differ on the replica?  And how is this related to multi-source?